# Create an instance for the class Scanner, but not for Math class in java?

Tags: java, class, math, java.util.scanner

Why do I have to create an instance for the class Scanner, but not for Math class in java?

I hope you guys can explain me this with good examples.

I understand it in this way:

We are asking the same in `Math.pow()` for examples.

It will always be the power of a number.. (x,y) for example or (x,2)

But `.print()` or `.println()` will change the value .. ? That's why we need to create an instance for the class Scanner.. am I right?

Edit: I do know it is static, but I need a more explained in detail answer then.. "its just the way it is"..

Comment: Because 'Math.pow()' is a static method, and doesn't use an instance.  It's just the way the class is designed.

Comment: You don't need an instance to call static methods. Simple as that. What kind of *examples* do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

`Math` defines only `static` methods because it doesn't contain internal states.

You could argue:

But what about polymorphism, what if I want to override `Math` class?

=> classic mathematical operations are unlikely to be overridden for most of 99% of programs.

So it acts as a simple **utility** class, waiting for inputs, and outputting some result in one call.

Answer (score 1):

See as an example [`Math#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-):

```
public static double max(double a, double b)
```

Since it's `static`, it means that it's not *associated* with any object. You can simply call it.

Now look at [`PrintStream#println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-boolean-):

```
public void println(boolean x)
```

Since it's *not* `static`, you cannot directly call it by writing `PrintStream.println(something)`.

Think about it, it really make sense that `max` is `static` since it doesn't have to be associated with an object, it doesn't really needs an information about an object as it doesn't care about it. It has a well defined behavior for all objects. No special treatment for some objects over others.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are acessing static methods of Math. Note you are using "class i.e. Math".method.

While for Scanner, you use instance as all the methods like `nextInt`, `next` are defined as non static.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Math` is private, meaning you cannot call it from outside `Math`.

The reason is that it is a class holding a bunch of static utility methods, and there is no need to ever generate an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

The methods on the Math class are `static` methods, whereas the ones for the Scanner class are not.

The Scanner class isn't using static methods because each instance needs to maintain their own state, different from other instances of Scanner.

The Math class are simple utility functions that have no state, so they can be static.